# When to use the chess tag?

Tags: discussion

Questions like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/255/129) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/180/129) are tagged [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), but one could argue that those problems don't involve anything about chess, except the fact that they use a *checkered board*.

Should these kind of problems be tagged [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess)?

Comment: Question: would questions like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7/11) and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/22/11) then be appropriate for the "chess" tag, as they deal with actual chess board and pieces?

Answer (score 3):

As I described in the comments of the first question you linked to, I don't believe the [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag is appropriate here. The question is not pertinent to the *game of chess* so much as to the board on which it is played. The question could just as easily have been about a checker board, but that doesn't imply that it should be tagged [checkers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkers).

The second question you linked to talks about a "pawn", but again it doesn't seem to be a "chess pawn" but rather a piece that has its own rules for moving.

Answer (score 3):

Arshajii does make a good point. I believe that the [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) must be kept for questions that actually deal with the rules of chess.

I suggest that questions that solely deal with the checkered board must be tagged [chessboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chessboard) while questions that actually deal with the rules of chess could be tagged [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess).

Comment: Agreed, except use [tag:checkerboard] instead of chessboard.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that a chessboard is in fact a type of checkerboard ([ref. Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard)), and in cases like these where it does not matter that the board is made specifically for chess, the more general term *checkerboard* (lit. "A checkered board") should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. Those two problems doesn't actually involve the game of chess in any way, just an 8-by-8 checkerboard (which I called a "chessboard" but we can rename that tag if you want to).

---

More recently, I saw [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-many-chess-pieces-does-it-take-to-cover-all-spaces-on-a-chessboard) which actually involves the chess pieces and how they move, which had the [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) tag removed. I put it back on before noticing that the last edit had been the removal of the tag. Should questions like those be tagged with chess?

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone seemed to be in favor of changing the tag to include *board*, I've gone ahead and made the change to all questions currently tagged *chess* (none of them were actually just about chess). They're currently pending approval so please go help out with that!

I selected *chessboard* rather than *checkerboard* because we seemed split on that, and you want to focus on usability: if someone is trying to type "chess", they will see the "chessboard" tag autocomplete and use that instead. If we used "checkerboard" people would keep misusing *chess* and we'd never fix the problem.

Comment: The chessboard/checkerboard problem can be fixed by making them tag synonyms (which would make sense to me).  As for your edits, I declined two of them, because those two actually referred to chess pieces (and their rules for movement), not just to the shape of the board itself.  If others disagree, they are free to edit the question - I won't decline it again.

Comment: @Xynariz I think the synonym is a great idea, and fair enough on the edits! I think there's a difference between a game of chess and chess pieces, but that could just be me.

Comment: I'd agree that there's a difference, but it makes sense to me to have [tag:chess] mean "some knowledge of chess rules comes into play in this question" rather than "this question is literally about the game of chess".